# How to explicitly declare charset=utf8 for Airflow connections

Tags: python, mysql, airflow

This sequence:

```
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook
conn = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='conn_id')
engine = conn.get_sqlalchemy_engine()
df.to_sql('test_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

produces the following:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character '\ufffd' in position 57: ordinal not in range(256)
```

This sequence works great:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql://{0}:{1}@{2}/capone?charset=utf8".format(user, pwd, host))
df.to_sql('test_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The key is in explicitly declaring the `charset`. I have attempted to do this in airflow as follows with `{"charset": "utf8"}`:

[image]

But this has not fixed the error. I've restarted my dev environment since making the changes and the admin panel lets me know that the edit was successful. How can I work with Airflow connections to my charsets as utf8?

Comment: What you have looks correct. [MySqlHook](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.py#L55-L59) establishes a connection with `MySQLdb.connect(..., charset='utf8', use_unicode=True)`, so it might be worth trying that out in shell directly. Also make sure you are selecting the correct `conn_id`!

Comment: odd. by "test in shell directly" to you mean something other than the two examples I provided here? and thanks, good to know i'm on the right track. i'll keep playing with it and make sure that I haven't scrambled my connections....

Comment: Did you ever find the issue? I have the exact same error going from a dataframe to_sql.

Comment: @lolcode man, it's been a bit. first, triple, triple check your connections like Daniel Huang suggested. second, make sure that the instance that you are writing to has its default charset to utf-8. if you're using AWS, for example, it will spin up the DB with `latin1` by default. you can override this by explicitly passing in `utf8`, but with the default set you can handle a lot of your write errors. if that works mind lettting me know so that I can write an answer?

Comment: It seems that Airflow has fixed this issue.  I am using Airflow 1.10.5.  Adding "charset" in "Extra" works.

Comment: Great news! I'm starting to play around with Dagster these days, but I'm glad to hear that the platform is making progress :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realised that this is a bug in Airflow and I have reported it here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-4824

For now I have a workaround with the following code:

```
def get_uri(hook):
    conn = hook.get_connection(getattr(hook, hook.conn_name_attr))
    login = ''
    if conn.login:
        login = '{conn.login}:{conn.password}@'.format(conn=conn)
    host = conn.host
    if conn.port is not None:
        host += ':{port}'.format(port=conn.port)
    charset = ''
    if conn.extra_dejson.get('charset', False):
        chrs = conn.extra_dejson["charset"]
        if chrs.lower() == 'utf8' or chrs.lower() == 'utf-8':
            charset = '?charset=utf8'
    return '{conn.conn_type}://{login}{host}/{conn.schema}{charset}'.format(
        conn=conn, login=login, host=host, charset=charset)
```

And then use it as follows:

```
url = get_uri(sql_hook)
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine(url)
```

The real solution will be to send a pull request to the project overriding get_uri in mysql_hook.py.

Comment: I extended `MySqlHook` to include this method, changing the `hook` parameter to `self`, and this worked perfectly. Nice one!

Answer (score 2):

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from airflow.hooks.mysql_hook import MySqlHook

conn = MySqlHook(mysql_conn_id='conn_id')
uri = conn.get_uri()
engine = create_engine(uri+'?charset=utf8')
df.to_sql('test_table', engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I fixed the problem by the code above.

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the problem by the way and work well (edited in file airflow.cfg):

```
sql_alchemy_conn = mysql://user:password@host:port/airflow?charset=utf8
```